# Override field to allow NULL in django model

Tags: django, django-models

Django user model works for me, but I want to make username nullable.

What is a clean way to do it?

Comment: You can use a custom user model to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a custom user model by extending the `AbstractBaseUser` class. There is a nice example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). As it is mentioned there, you just need to have some sort of unique identifier for the user that will be used for authentication. I hope that helps.